# Paypal not getting Return values in Success page for mobile devices(Android,Ipad,Iphone)

Tags: php, paypal

I have an issue in my mobile devices(Android,Ipad,Iphone) when redirecting page from Paypal payments to success page, the success page doesn’t get any values.

I had tried to print the output, but gets no values(Null Values) in succes page from checking in Mobile devices.

In Desktop(PC) browser its working fine and printing values in success page

Please provide me a solution soon.

Comment: Hi, Did you get a solution